# Spring security. unbelievable behavior

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have very strange spring security behaviour.

security configuration:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
   <http use-expressions="true" >   

        <intercept-url pattern="/home.jsp" access="permitAll" /> 

        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/> 


        <form-login login-page="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" default-target-url="/index" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logOut" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="provider" /> 
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping("/index")
public String success(Model model) {
    System.out.println("/index");
    return "index";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/loginFailed", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String loginError(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes ) throws Exception {
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "incorrect combination of login and password");
    System.out.println("/loginFailed");
    return "redirect:home.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/logOut", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String logOut(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "success logout");
    System.out.println("/logOut");
    return "redirect:home.jsp";
}
    ...
}
```

if on url `http://localhost:8080/ui/`(root application url) I type

first activity:

1  input correct password   -->  `http://localhost:8080/ui/index`  in log I see `/index` `isAuthenttificated() == true`

2  press logOut    -->  `http://localhost:8080/ui/`  and log is empty `isAuthenttificated() == false`

3  input correct password   --> `http://localhost:8080/ui/home.jsp?message=success+logout` and I see `/logOut` in console `isAuthenttificated() == true`

4 press logOut --> go to  `http://localhost:8080/ui/`  and log is empty `isAuthenttificated() == false`

5  input correct password --> go to    `http://localhost:8080/ui/`  and log is empty `isAuthenttificated() == false`

I don't understand rules what spring  security select which controller to use.

I think spring invokes right servlets but use wrong urls.

Comment: Spring security will redirect to either `default-target-url` or the page you redirected from to get authentication. If you wish to always forward to the default target use `always-use-default-target="true"`

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed is that you probably forgot to add the following configuration

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginFailed" access="permitAll" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
```

Or at least all pages which are related to login/error pages should usually be exempted from authentication.

Comment: iI don't see changes after it